# Delete an Outlook appointment if a cell contains specific text

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I currently have a code set up to add an appointment to Outlook if a cell in Excel contains the word "No". What I would like to be able to do is delete an existing appointment if the same cell is changed to "N/A". I've tried to adapt some code I found elsewhere for this but can't get it to work, currently it's displaying "Compile error: next without for"

```
Sub DeleteCalendarItems()

Dim r As Long, i As Long, wb              As Workbook
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim objOutlook      As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace    As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder       As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objAppointment  As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim strSubject      As String

Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = objFolder.Items
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Section 74")


r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Rows.Count should also have a reference to a wb & ws
For i = 2 To r

    If ws.Cells(i, 9) = "N/A" Then
                ws.Cells(i, 13) = "Yes"
        Set objAppointment = oItems.Item(i)
        With objAppointment
            If .Subject = strSubject Then
                objAppointment.Delete
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A `With`, `If` and `For` statement (and more) should always be closed

```
Sub DeleteCalendarItems()
Dim wb              As Workbook
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim objOutlook      As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace    As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder       As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objAppointment  As Outlook.AppointmentItem
Dim strSubject      As String

Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = objFolder.Items
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Section 74")


r = ES.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Rows.Count should also have a reference to a wb & ws
For i = 2 To r

    If ES.Cells(i, 9).Value = "N/A" Then
        Set objAppointment = oItems.Item(i)
        With objAppointment
            If .Subject = strSubject Then
                objAppointment.Delete
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm now trying to set it so it enters a "Yes" in a cell when it is deleted (code amended above) but am getting "method or data error not found"?

Comment: You are referring to `ES` which is undefined. You are also setting objects `wb` and `ws` but never using them in the code.  If you want to refer to `wb.Worksheets("Section 74")`, you'll have to replace `ES` with `ws`

Comment: I've set ES in the amended code as above already, when I debug it highlights  `.AppointmentItem` in `Set objAppointment = Outlook.AppointmentItem`

Comment: Try `Set objAppointment = objOutlook.AppointmentItem`. Also, your closing statements are all shuffled in your amended code. I highly advise you to use proper indentation.

Comment: I'm now getting "Expected function or variable" on the `.Delete` part of `With objAppointment.Delete` ?

Comment: Because you can't use that line.. `objAppointment.Delete.Save` would also be a nonsense line. It would be better if you were to use my code and change `ES` in that.

Comment: I'm not sure what to change `If .Subject = strSubject Then` in the code to so that it looks for the N/A in the cell to delte the appointment?

Comment: `strSubject` is an empty variable since you never populate it. So you are checking whether the subject of `objAppointment` is empty.
Perhaps you should carefully read through your code to see what it is doing.

Comment: I'm a complete amateur with VBA and only picking little bits up as I go along, so not sure at all what to change that part to so it checks for "N/A" in a cell

Comment: Is it the string "N/A", or do you check for a formula returning the "#N/A" error? For the former, your code is correct. For the latter, use `= "Error 2042" Then` instead of `= "N/A" Then`.

Comment: It's the string "N/A", sorry. I changed the subject section to be `If .Subject = "Send reminder email - " + ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                objAppointment.Delete` but again this doesn't delete the appointment

Comment: Then I would check whether that is truly the subject of the appointment you are trying to delete. Use `F8` to step through the code line-by-line. I can't help you any further

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to work it out (somehow) - I needed to add a nested `For` loop

```
Sub DeleteNASec74()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim wb              As Workbook
Dim ws              As Worksheet
Dim objOutlook      As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace    As Outlook.Namespace
Dim objFolder       As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objAppointment  As Outlook.AppointmentItem

Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
Set oItems = objFolder.Items
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Section 74")


r = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To r
For j = oItems.Count To 1 Step -1
    If ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = "N/A" Then
    ws.Cells(i, 13) = "Yes"
        Set objAppointment = oItems.Item(j)
        With objAppointment
            If .Subject = "Send reminder email - " + ws.Cells(i, 2).Value Then
                objAppointment.Delete
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next j
Next i
End Sub
```